# How to use multiple namespaces in a PHP file including the root namespace?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, copy, root

I'm doing some work on my framework, and I want to create some classes which are copies of Eloquent classes under the root namespace.

However, this doesn't work. (**Fatal error**: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call.)

```
<?php

  //Create Alternate Namespaces for Eloquent Classes
  class Blueprint extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint {};
  class Eloquent extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {};
  class DB extends \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager {};

  namespace BareBones;

  //Require Composer Dependencies
  require_once("../libs/BareBones/autoload.php");

  //Require Core Classes
  require_once("barebones/app.php");
  require_once("barebones/controller.php");
  require_once("barebones/model.php");

  \Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

And this doesn't work either (**Parse error:**  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting identifier (T_STRING))...

```
<?php

  namespace BareBones;

  //Require Composer Dependencies
  require_once("../libs/BareBones/autoload.php");

  //Require Core Classes
  require_once("barebones/app.php");
  require_once("barebones/controller.php");
  require_once("barebones/model.php");

  \Twig_Autoloader::register();

  //Create Alternate Namespaces for Eloquent Classes
  namespace \;

  class Blueprint extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint {};
  class Eloquent extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {};
  class DB extends \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager {};
```

I don't want to include this in an alternate file. I want these simple configurations to be in the framework's `init` file. Can this be accomplished in one file?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: @Sammitch Yes. I know about that. But I don't want the users of my framework (or me for that matter) to use the fully qualified reference. I want them to be able to use it under a shallow namespace, in any file.

Comment: Well: 1. That's a really bad idea, to the point of asking why you're even bothering to use namespaces in the first place? 2. That's something that you should leave up to the users of your framework.